Unexpire all past chrome flags
I dislike the UI changes Chrome brought in late 2023 and 2024, therefore I did not bother upgrading. I'm still on Chrome 118 as a result, which is extremely bad security-wise. I should use the newest browser, but I want the old UI. There used to be some flags to revert back to the old UI, which has been removed. Currently chrome only allows showing the flags removed from the 2 most recent versions.
Is there a way to force all historical flags to show, or to configure the newest version of chrome to use the old UI? If not, what would be my best option if I still want the same UI but stay up-to-date security wise?

No, once the flags have been removed there is no way to add them back, unless you want to build Chromium yourself and make the changes yourself

With flags they also likely removed or deprecated and are about to remove some of the customization from the code
